# httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync .NET Core 3.1 returns empty items with a converter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, httpclient, blazor

I'm working on a blazor application webassembly core hosted, and when I'm trying to get a collection of items from the server, I get the right number of items but they are all empty.

My models look like this :

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : IPerson
{
    public decimal CreditLimit { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : IPerson
{
    public string OfficeNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float SomeParameters { get; set; }
    
    public IPerson Person { get; set; }
}
```

And I implemented a converter with the TypeDiscriminator template : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#support-polymorphic-deserialization

Using client side :

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new PersonConverterWithTypeDiscriminator());
return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Model>>(baseAPIUri, options);
```

Using server side :

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new NullableStructSerializerFactory());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new PersonConverterWithTypeDiscriminator());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true;
    });
```

Everithings works well when the client send the model to the server to save it, with `httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(baseAPIUri, item, options);`

But when the client asks for the collection, I enter in the write() method, and never in the read() method in the convertor.

I tried to retrive the items without the serializer options and if the parameter Person is null, the deserialization is correct.

EDIT : I copied the Http response content in a file, created a new project .Net core in a console and add the lines :

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        IgnoreNullValues = true,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true
    };
    options.Converters.Add(new NullableStructSerializerFactory());
    options.Converters.Add(new PersonConverterWithTypeDiscriminator());
    
string json = File.ReadAllText("D:\\model.json");
var newModel = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Model>>(json, options);
```

And it worked out

Comment: Did you try to reset all serializer's options as you do for the default serializer. It's not an override but a replace.

Comment: Yeah i set exactly the same options, but it doens't change anything

Comment: I use a lot of other models in my application, but I have this issue only with this type of model, containing an interface type.
I have some other converter for the same reason, but when I use them it is only to transfert the interfaced model or a collection of them. It is the first time I try to transfert a model containing a interfaced parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again this morning, and it worked....
So the solution was the well known 'shut up and reboot' method